# Lights not working

Tags: rendering, lighting

So the lights on my scene are not working at all, I point light, spot, sun, area nothing works

[image: Photo]

I tried also changing the values and the radius of the lights not working at all scene light are also turned on

Won't work on viewport and it won't work on rendering

My object has a refractive shader on it and if I crank up the world lights a bit I can see my object but the spot light still won't work

Never happened before ? Any solutions ?

Thanks

Comment: I see 2.93.4 on Windows 10? Is this happening with a single blend file or all your files? If it's a single file, perhaps you can share it with us?

Comment: Does diffuse shader work?

Comment: it's windows 10 yeah, other files are okay I guess I'll just try and move all my objects to a new file, but it's weird why the lights won't work...

Comment: can u provide your blend file?

Answer (score -2):

First make sure:

- The World space is right. If the light is to far away from the object, it doesn't light anything up.
- The light is in the same collection as the "lit" object (or linked to it)

Comment: Light objects don't need to be in the same collection as objects

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

But both options won't work, it doesn't matter where I put the light relative to the object, even If I put it on top of it still won't work